# How should I backup pillar data for SaltStack?

Tags: saltstack

It makes sense to backup the salt state to a git repo since there shouldn't be any sensitive data in there.

But what about the pillar data? Should I just create a separate git repo for that, or put it in an S3 bucket, or encrypt the data somehow?

Comment: You can encrypt your pillar data with PGP and secure the key on your salt-master, so that your pillar data does not show private information in your git repository. Salt can render state files with a PGP renderer.

Comment: Nice, that is probably close to what I want.

Comment: Good to hear! I have put my comment down as an answer with more details for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can encrypt your pillar data with GPG and secure the key on your salt-master, so that your pillar data does not show private information in your git repository.

Salt can render state files with a GPG renderer.

You can set something like this in your master configuration to enable the renderer:

```
renderer: jinja | yaml | gpg
```

An example format is as follows:

```
secret-data: |
  -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
  Version: GnuPG v1

  hQEMAweRHKaPCfNeAQf9GLTN16hCfXAbPwU6BbBK0unOc7i9/etGuVc5CyU9Q6um
  QuetdvQVLFO/HkrC4lgeNQdM6D9E8PKonMlgJPyUvC8ggxhj0/IPFEKmrsnv2k6+
  cnEfmVexS7o/U1VOVjoyUeliMCJlAz/30RXaME49Cpi6No2+vKD8a4q4nZN1UZcG
  RhkhC0S22zNxOXQ38TBkmtJcqxnqT6YWKTUsjVubW3bVC+u2HGqJHu79wmwuN8tz
  m4wBkfCAd8Eyo2jEnWQcM4TcXiF01XPL4z4g1/9AAxh+Q4d8RIRP4fbw7ct4nCJv
  Gr9v2DTF7HNigIMl4ivMIn9fp+EZurJNiQskLgNbktJGAeEKYkqX5iCuB1b693hJ
  FKlwHiJt5yA8X2dDtfk8/Ph1Jx2TwGS+lGjlZaNqp3R1xuAZzXzZMLyZDe5+i3RJ
  skqmFTbOiA==
  =Eqsm
  -----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

You can also apply the renderer on a file-by-file basis by adding the following line to the top of any pillar with gpg data in it:

```
#!yaml|gpg
```

See the documentation here:
http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/all/salt.renderers.gpg.html